# Finding palindromes and reverse strings in C

Tags: c, palindrome

I've created a program that will find if a word is a palindrome or a reverse string (`emordnilap`).

*How it works:*

The palindrome part works by reversing the string, and comparing the two strings using `strcmp` to see if they match one another. If they do match, it will return true, if they do not match false.

How it checks if the word is a reverse string is by running through a wordlist line by line, stripping the string using a strip function and testing if the word is in the wordlist. Examples of usage:

```
e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -h
usage: epi -h -t -s [string] [file]

-h       Print this help and exit

-t       Run the test strings.

-s       Input a string to check if it is either a palindrome or
         a emordinlap, followed by the path to a file.
e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -t

'a' is a palindrome, it is the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'a' is a emordnilap, it spells a word backwards.


'ab' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'ab' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards


'abc' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'abc' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards


'another' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'another' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards


'cbc' is a palindrome, it is the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'cbc' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards


'|0|' is a palindrome, it is the same forward and backwards
Reverse of '|0|' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards


'palindrome' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'palindrome' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards // technically emordnilap is not a word

e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -s 

You must provide a string to test.

usage: epi -h -t -s [string] [file]

-h       Print this help and exit

-t       Run the test strings.

-s       Input a string to check if it is either a palindrome or
         a emordnilap, followed by the path to a file.
e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -s test

You must pass a valid file path to use as a wordlist.

usage: epi -h -t -s [string] [file]

-h       Print this help and exit

-t       Run the test strings.

-s       Input a string to check if it is either a palindrome or
         a emordinlap, followed by the path to a file.
e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -s test test.txt

'test' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'test' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards

e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$ ./epi.exe -s tset test.txt

'tset' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards
Reverse of 'tset' is a emordnilap, it spells a word backwards.

e@ubuntu:~/bin/c$
```

Key points that I would like to focus on, of course critique the entire program:

- Is there a better way to reverse a string?
- Running through a file list, am I doing it properly?
- Could this program be simplified?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static void *helpPage(void)
{
    puts("usage: epi -h -t -s [string] [file]\n");
    puts("-h       Print this help and exit\n");
    puts("-t       Run the test strings.\n");
    puts("-s       Input a string to check if it is either a palindrome or");
    puts("         a emordnilap, followed by the path to a file.");;
}

static char *reverse(char *str)
{
    // reverse a given string

    char tmp, *src, *dst;
    size_t len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        if (len > 1)
        {
            src = str;
            dst = src + len - 1;

            while (src < dst)
            {
                tmp = *src;
                *src++ = *dst;
                *dst-- = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

static char *strip(char *s)
{
    // strip a string of a new line

    return strtok(s, "\n");
}

static bool checkEpi(char *reversed, char *filePath)
{
    // check if the word matches in a given file
    // or if the word is an emordnilap

    FILE *wordList;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    wordList = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (wordList == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file :"); // file probably doesn't exit
    }
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, wordList)) != -1) // read the file line by line
    {
        if (strcmp(strip(line), reversed) == 0)
        {
            return true; // return true if the word matches
        }
    }
    fclose(wordList);
}

static bool checkPali(char *origin, char *reversed)
{
    // check if a given word is a palindrome or not

    if (strcmp(origin, reversed) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static void checkAll(char *origin, char* reverse, char *filePath)
{
    // basically a main function to check if it's a palindrome or a emordnilap

    bool paliRes = checkPali(origin, reverse);
    bool epiRes = checkEpi(reverse, filePath);
    if (paliRes == true)
    {
        printf("\n'%s' is a palindrome, it is the same forward and backwards\n", origin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n'%s' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards\n", origin);
    }

    if (epiRes == true)
    {
        printf("Reverse of '%s' is a emordnilap, it spells a word backwards.\n\n", origin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reverse of '%s' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards\n\n", origin);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        puts("\nYou failed to pass a valid flag...\n");
        helpPage();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        char *testStrings[] = {"a", "ab", "abc", "another", "cbc", "|0|", "palindrome"};
        int i;
        char s[10000];
        char *defaultWordList = "/usr/share/dict/american-english";
        size_t optInt;

        for (optInt = 1; optInt < argc && argv[optInt][0] == '-'; optInt++)
        {
            switch(argv[optInt][1])
            {
                case 't':
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(testStrings) / sizeof(testStrings[0]); i++)
                    {
                        strcpy(s, testStrings[i]);
                        char *origin = testStrings[i];
                        char *revStr = reverse(s);
                        checkAll(origin, revStr, defaultWordList);
                    }
                    return 0;
                }

                case 's':
                {
                    if (argv[2] == NULL)
                    {
                        puts("\nYou must provide a string to test.\n");
                        helpPage();
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (argv[3] == NULL)
                    {
                        puts("\nYou must pass a valid file path to use as a wordlist.\n");
                        helpPage();
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy(s, argv[2]);
                        char *revStr = reverse(s);
                        checkAll(argv[2], revStr, argv[3]);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

                case 'h': helpPage(); return 0;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Took only a quick look. Congratulations for quite clean code style. Some of your function parameters can be made 'const'. Also it might be a good idea to validate each argument at the beginning of the function (Especially in C, espeacially when using pointers).

Comment: @fer-rum Thanks for noticing, I try hard to keep my code clean, and thanks for the tip

Comment: Why does _helpPage()_ suggest to return a void pointer (and then return nothing at all)? Double semicolon spotted. Note that _printf_ is discouraged for real-world production use, since it can be used in exploits.

Comment: @fer-rum To be 100% honest with you, it's because I have absolutely no idea what the hell I'm doing when it comes to C lol. How can `printf` be used for exploitation?

Comment: @jakehimton: The most possibly irrelevant comment coming through: you have misspelled word "emordinlap" in the last line of your `helpPage` function.

Comment: @Przemek Omg.. I am so dumb, lol thank you

Comment: You should be able to compare forward and reverse in-place without needing any copying  (admittedly much easier in C++, where forward and reverse iterators are provided for you).

Comment: @jakehimton Here is a nice comprehensive guide on how to exploit the formatstring weaknesses of *printf*: https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28476.pdf To circumvent these it is recommended to use *fprintf()* instead.

Answer (score 4):

*First off*: I really like reading your code. The code style looks clean and the intend of all variables seem clear to the reader - good naming. This was pretty quick and I may revisit this post later - don't have enough time right now.

Here are some things I noticed (in no particular order):

- You declared the function `helpPage(void)` to return `void *`, but never return anything. You probably just meant to write `void`. Also I would've replaced `helpPage` with `printHelpPage`.
- Declare variables when you first use them. This makes the intend more clear to the reader. Example in `reverse(char *str)`:

  ```
  // Reverse a given null-terminated string
  static char *reverse(char *str)
  {
      if (str != NULL)
      {
          size_t len = strlen(str);

          if (len > 1)
          {
              char *src, *dst;
              src = str;
              dst = src + len - 1;

              while (src < dst)
              {
                  char tmp = *src;
                  *src++ = *dst;
                  *dst-- = tmp;
              }
          }
      }
      return str;
  }
  ```

  I think this makes the use of each variable easier to understand, otherwise
  the reader could be confused (*What do I need all these variables for?*).
- I'm not sure if creating an extra function `strip(char *s)` for a single `strtok` call is really necessary.
- Pay attention to *`const` correctness* in `checkEpi`: Mark `reversed` and `filePath` const, since `checkEpi` doesn't modify them through these pointers:

  ```
  static bool checkEpi(const char *reversed, const char *filePath);
  ```

  Same with `checkPali` / `checkAll`.
- Handle failed `fopen`. You do print and error message using `perror`, but the function should return right after printing the error.
- **Memory leak** in `checkEpi`. `getline` will allocate memory for `line` and you are responsible for freeing it later on.
- I don't see a `return` statement in `checkEpi` beside from the `return true`. Explicitly return `false`!
- `checkPali` shouldn't expect the original *and* the reversed string. The function should check if a single string is a palindrome (the reversing happens inside `checkPali`)  - same thing in `checkAll`.
- Take a look at your current `checkPali` implementation. **Never** write code like this:

  ```
  if (something) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  but instead write `return something;` right away .
- `checkAll`: Your current code assigns the return values of `checkPali` and `checkEpi` to variables named and `paliRes` and `epiRes` and later on checks them with `paliRes == true`. Consider renaming these variables to `isPalindrome` and `isEmordnilap` and using them like `if(isPalindrome) ...`, etc.
- *Minor*: I probably would've defined `testStrings` and `defaultWordList` at the top of the file via the `#define`-directive.
- *Minor*: You accidentally put one semicolon too many into `helpPage(void)`.

**This is what I came up with:**

*(The code should just give you a rough example on how to do it. I'm currently in a rush, so please excuse any mistakes made)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void printHelpPage(void) {
    puts("Usage: epi -h -t -s [string] [file]\n");
    puts("-h       Print this help and exit\n");
    puts("-t       Run the test strings.\n");
    puts("-s       Input a string to check if it is either a palindrome or");
    puts("         a emordnilap, followed by the path to a file.");
}

// In-place reverse null-terminated string
static char *reverse(char *str) {
    size_t len;
    if (str != NULL && (len = strlen(str)) > 1) {
        char *src, *dest;
        src = str;
        dest = src + len - 1;

        while (src < dest) {
            char tmp = *src;
            *src++ = *dest;
            *dest-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

// Return values: -1 on error, 0 for no Emordnilap, 1 for Emordnilap
static int checkEmordnilap(const char *str, const char *filePath) {
    char *reversed = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    if (!reversed) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory to store reversed string ");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(reversed, str);
    reverse(reversed);

    FILE *wordListFile = fopen(filePath, "r");

    if (!wordListFile) {
        free(reversed);
        perror("Failed to open wordList ");
        return -1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;

    while((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, wordListFile)) > 0) {
      if (strcmp(strtok(line, "\n"), reversed) == 0) {
        return 1;
      }
    }

    fclose(wordListFile);
    free(reversed);

    return 0;
}


// Return -1 on error, 0 on no palindrome, 1 on palindrome
static int checkPalidrome(const char *str) {
    char *reversed = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    if (!reversed) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory to store reversed string.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(reversed, str);
    reverse(reversed);

    int result = strcmp(str, reversed) == 0;
    free(reversed);

    return result;
}

static void printStatus(const char *origin, const char *filePath) {
    int isPalindrome, isEmordnilap;
    isPalindrome = checkPalidrome(origin);
    isEmordnilap = checkEmordnilap(origin, filePath);

    if (isPalindrome == -1 || isEmordnilap == -1) {
        // We already see the error message printed from checkPalindrome/checkEmordnilap.
        return;
    }

    if (isPalindrome) {
        printf("\n'%s' is a palindrome, it is the same forward and backwards\n", origin);
    } else {
        printf("\n'%s' is not a palindrome, it is not the same forward and backwards\n", origin);
    }

    if (isEmordnilap) {
        printf("Reverse of '%s' is a emordnilap, it spells a word backwards.\n\n", origin); 
    } else {
        printf("Reverse of '%s' is not a emordnilap, it does not spell a word backwards\n\n", origin);
    }
}

#define TEST_STRINGS { "a", "ab", "abc", "another", "|0|", "palindrome" }
#define DEFAULT_WORD_LIST "/usr/share/dict/propernames"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
      printHelpPage();
      return 1;
  }

  for (int argNum = 1; argNum < argc && argv[argNum][0] == '-'; ++argNum) {
      switch(argv[argNum][1]) {
          case 't': {
              char *testStrings[] = TEST_STRINGS;
              for (size_t wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < sizeof(testStrings)/sizeof(testStrings[0]); ++wordIndex) {
                  printStatus(testStrings[wordIndex], DEFAULT_WORD_LIST);
              }
              break;
          }
          case 's':
              if (argc < 3) {
                  puts("\nYou must provide a string to test.\n");
                  printHelpPage();
                  return 1;
              }
              char *wordList = argc < 4 ? DEFAULT_WORD_LIST : argv[4];
              printStatus(argv[2], wordList);
              break;
          case 'h':
              continue;
          default:
              printHelpPage();
              break;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `(str != NULL)` is not needed as `str`, as a *string*, is never `NULL`.  In C, a *string* is a sequence (e.g. array) of characters up to and including the terminating *null character*.

Still it is not a bad idea to check against `NULL` for as a pointer, `char *` sometimes will be assigned `NULL`.

The `if (len > 1)` can be eliminated by taking advantage of starting with `right` assigned to the address of the *null character*.

```
static char *reverse(char *str) {
  char *left = str;
  char *right = str + strlen(str);
  while (right > left) {
    right--;
    char tmp = *right;
    *right = *left;
    *left = tmp;
    left++;
  }
  return str;
}
```